# post unsuccessful in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have a very basic code that implements basic http post. When I clicked to button, I expect that the execution flow to        "public ActionResult DepositToAcount(DepositToAccountView model)" but it hasn't. What am I missing? Here is the code: Thanks in advance.

```
  public class MainController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult DepositToAcount()
    {
        FindAllBankAccountResponse response = null;
        DepositToAccountView viewmodel = null;

        try
        {
            response = new ApplicationBankAccountService().GetAllBankAccounts();
            viewmodel = new DepositToAccountView();

            viewmodel.SetupList(response);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

        return View(viewmodel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DepositToAcount(DepositToAccountView model)
    {
        //code execution never reachs there.
        DepositToAccountView gorunum = null;

        try
        {
            gorunum = new DepositToAccountView();
            //deposit implementation

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

        return View(gorunum);
    }
}
```

Here is the view :

```
@model AppService.ViewModel.DepositToAccountView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deposit To Acount Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChosenAccount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChosenAccount, Model.AccountList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChosenAccount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmountToBeDeposited, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountToBeDeposited, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmountToBeDeposited, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Deposit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the DepositToAccountView :

```
 public class DepositToAccountView
{
    private string _amountToBeDeposited;
    private string _chosenAccount;
    private List<SelectListItem> _accountList;

    public List<SelectListItem> AccountList
    {
        get
        {
            return _accountList;
        }

        set
        {
            _accountList = value;
        }
    }


    [Display(Name = "Para Eklemek İstediğiniz Hesabı Seçiniz:")]
    public string ChosenAccount
    {
        get
        {
            return this._chosenAccount;
        }

        set
        {
            this._chosenAccount = value;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Eklenecek miktarı giriniz: ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen bir miktar giriniz.")]
    public string AmountToBeDeposited
    {
        get
        {
            return this._amountToBeDeposited;
        }

        set
        {
            this._amountToBeDeposited = value;
        }
    }

    public DepositToAccountView()
    {
        this.AccountList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public void SetupList(FindAllBankAccountResponse Response)
    {
        SelectListItem item = null;

        try
        {
            if (Response == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.allDefaultValueToList();

            foreach (BankAccountView gorunum in Response.BankAccountView)
            {
                item = new SelectListItem();
                item.Text = gorunum.CustomerRef;
                item.Value = gorunum.AccountNo.ToString();
                this.AccountList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private void allDefaultValueToList()
    {
        SelectListItem secinizHesap = new SelectListItem();
        secinizHesap.Value ="0";
        secinizHesap.Text = "Hesap Seçiniz";

        this.AccountList.Add(secinizHesap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have no `<form>`. What is it supposed to submit? :)

So if you change your view like this:

```
@model AppService.ViewModel.DepositToAccountView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deposit To Acount Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChosenAccount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChosenAccount, Model.AccountList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChosenAccount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmountToBeDeposited, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountToBeDeposited, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmountToBeDeposited, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Deposit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
}
```

It should work as expected. `Html.BeginForm()` here adds the starting form element, and when it is disposed at the end of the `using` statement, it writes the end element.